# Glimpse Asp.net not debugging jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, debugging, glimpse

I am using Glimpse 1.5 and jquery 1.7.2.
I cannot debug ajax calls; nothing shows up in the ajax tab. 
I use jquery.ajax in $(document).ready() and button clicks.
I have added some contentTypes to my webconfig but this does not help.

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
  <logging level="Trace" />
  <runtimePolicies>
    <contentTypes>
      <add contentType="text/plain"/>
      <add contentType="application/json"/>
      <add contentType="text/json"/>
      <add contentType="application/xml"/>
      <add contentType="text/xml"/>
    </contentTypes>
    <ignoredTypes>
      <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet"/>
    </ignoredTypes>
  </runtimePolicies>
</glimpse>
```

Has anyone else had this issue? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
The ajax calls are hitting WebMethods on the server side aspx pages.

Comment: Where are you `AJAX` calls going? To the server or outside the bounds of your server?

Comment: The ajax calls are hitting WebMethods on the code behind of the aspx pages (my server). I'm using web forms.

Comment: Can you share your log file? The log file tells you why any given request is ignored by Glimpse.

Comment: I've gotten glimpse to start showing my ajax request; however, it doesn't show my entity framework statements in the sql tab. Is there a special initialization function i have to call for Glimpse to profile EF SQL during ajax request?

Comment: you've gotten it to start showing ajax requests how ?

Comment: Glimpse doesn't currently capture calls to WebMethods in ASPX pages. I recently opened a github issue about this: https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/596

(the comments clearly describe why these calls aren't being reported)